# Problem with a while loop in C# - returns multiple

Tags: c#, console-application

I am new to C# (1 week in) and I have been scratching my head with no answers. Simply put this is part of a text based game out of much larger file. The player has the option to accept or decline an incoming call. If y/Y or n/N is entered all is well. If I purposely enter an incorrect character the `while` loop will print "Please respond with 'Y' or 'N' only.." 3 times. I cannot work out why. If you enter 2 letters such as GG it will print it 4 times, 3 letters, 5 times and so on. I know this is an easy fix, I just need someone to point out what I've done wrong.

```cs
//INCOMING CALL
static void IncomingCall(char rawResponse)
{
    // Convert response to upper
    // (note method as ToUpper cannot be called conventionally on type char)
    char response = char.ToUpper(rawResponse);
    while (response != 'Y' && response != 'N')
    {
        WriteLine("Please respond with 'Y' or 'N' only..");
        rawResponse = (char)Read();
        response = char.ToUpper(rawResponse);
    }
}
```

```cs
//called in main elsewhere in the file..
WriteLine("Incoming call from Tony. Press 'Y' to accept or 'N' to decline.");
char getInput = (char)Read();
IncomingCall(getInput);
```

Comment: You type a letter and press Enter. Your `IncomingCall` receives the letter, the `\r` and the `\n`. You type GG and press Enter. Your `IncomingCall` receives `G`, `G`, `\r`, `\n`. You have made your life harder for no reason by using `Read`. You should have used `ReadLine`.

Comment: I did try with ReadLine(), but get the error " Cannot convert type 'string' to 'char' " I did not realise Read() passes escape characters as arguments to the method. I had assumed ReadLine() returned a string and Read() returned a char, but I am probably incorrect.

Comment: You are correct. `Read()` returns a char, one at a time. Why would it decide to randomly ignore some of them? Your `IncomingCall` must accept a string, and it should not call `Read` itself.

Comment: In that scenario, why not pass in a `string`?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it, with your help by changing method to accept string and use ReadLine()

Changed

```
(response != 'Y' && response != 'N')
```

To

```
(response != "Y" && response != "N")
```

I did not realise '' and "" produce different results. I am used to Python. Thanks for the input guys.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest changing the design. Let's implement `ReadBool` methods which incapsulates all the logic of `bool` value input:

```
    public static bool ReadBool(string title) {
      // We keep asking user until valid (N or Y) value is entered
      while (true) {
        // If we have a title, let's show it 
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(title))
          Console.WriteLine(title);

        // User has to press 'Y' or 'N'; no need for enter
        var key = Console.ReadKey();

        if (key.KeyChar == 'Y')
          return true;
        if (key.KeyChar == 'N')
          return false;

        // Invalid value; let user know it and try again
        Console.WriteLine("Please respond with 'Y' or 'N' only..");
      }
    }
```

Possible usage:

```
bool acceptTony = ReadBool("Incoming call from Tony. Press 'Y' to accept or 'N' to decline.");

if (acceptTony) {
  Console.WriteLine("Hi Tony!");
  //TODO: put relevant code here
}
else {
  Console.WriteLine("Declined");
  //TODO: put relevant code here
}
```

Comment: I have yet to learn about ReadBool, but this looks really interesting. Thanks for taking the time to show me this.

Answer (score -1):

Swap `Read()` with `Console.Readline()[0];`.

EDIT: Or change your method signature to be a `string` and leverage `Console.Readline()` as stated in the comments prior.

Comment: Changed from char getInput = Read(); to string getInput = ReadLine(); and changed the method to accept a string instead of char. Returns the error Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'char.  Maybe I should go back to studying !

Comment: You'll also need to swap the type for `response` to be a string too. The error is telling you that you're comparing a `string` against a `char`.